# How can I contribute without using PayPal?

Tags: contributing

I'd like to contribute to Ubuntu development, but after [PayPal's questionable behavior with ProtonMail crowdsourcing](https://protonmail.ch/blog/paypal-freezes-protonmail-campaign-funds/) I'd like to avoid using them.  Are there other ways to share?  BitCoin? Check?

Answer (score 2):

I saw a notice a few months back stating that there will be more payment method added but that for now the best way was to purchase from the giftshop at http://shop.ubuntu.com/ They accept visa, mastercard, maestro, paypal, worldpay.

If you want purchase a bunch of DVDs and give them away or get a few T-shirts. You contribute to Ubuntu but also get something back for it. Better than just giving away money.