# Why doesn't Canonical/Ubuntu accept bitcoin contributions?

Tags: bitcoin, contributing, donation

I see many questions here about alternatives to Paypal, but no concrete information about why bitcoin (aka universal, Open Source and Free, community-driven money which does not discriminate based on economic status or geography)... is not accepted?!

It makes no sense and seems to directly contradict the [philosophy of this community](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy).

Is there a discussion of this decision we can take part in?
Or someone specific who is in charge of the [Contribution page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=14.04.3&architecture=amd64)?

Comment: you need to bring this to canonical directly i believed.

Comment: perhaps this should go to [meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/) tagged as feature-request? edit: oops, i see you mean ubuntu, not askubuntu

Comment: No idea. Same q from a while ago: http://askubuntu.com/questions/539459/how-can-i-contribute-without-using-paypal

Comment: Why was this flagged as off-topic?  The `donation` tag indicates this is for "Questions about donating to Canonical/Ubuntu project."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no concrete reason. [This guy](http://www.jonobacon.org/contact/) said "other payment mechanisms are currently being explored" ([source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/ubuntu-adds-new-donations-page)) 3 years ago. So maybe ask him about how it's going. Opening a bitcoin wallet and emptying it in exchange for the currency employees are paid in, isn't much work to do.